# JQuery does not change element with `active` class when element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a bootstarp nav-bar. Since bootstrap does not automatically switch `active` tab when tavs are clicked, I have written some JQuery to do this for me. I have done this before, and I cannot figure out what I a doing wrong.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public\bootstrap-3.3.2-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public\bootstrap-3.3.2-dist\css\bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public\styles\style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="public\bootstrap-3.3.2-dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="public\js\script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
  <h1><em>This is a test</em></h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="tab" class="active"><a href="1.html">Page 1</a></li>
    <li id="tab"><a href="1.html" target="content">Page 2</a></li>
    <li id="tab"><a href="1.html" target="content">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

My JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tab').click(function(event) {
    $('.active:first').removeClass('active');
    el = event.target;
    el.addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Whenever I click a tab, it should get the first element with the `active` class, remove the `active` class, and then add the `active` class to the element that was clicked. But it does not work. When I click the tab, it does nothing but follow the link. I tried changing the use of the pseudo class `:first` to use Jquery's `.first()` but that did not work. Again I have done this before, but cant get it to work now. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `.addClass()` method on a non-jQuery object.

Wrap `event.target` with `$()` --> `$(event.target)`

```
$('.tab').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(event.target).closest('.tab').addClass('active');
});
```

A few side notes:

- `id`s must be unique, they should *not* be duplicated. Use classes instead.
- Since your're clicking on anchor elements use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior.
- Since `$(event.target)` is the element being clicked, it will contain the anchor element if it is clicked. Since the `active` class should be on the parent, `li` element, you can either select it using `$(event.target).closest('.tab')` as in the example above. Or, since the event handler is already attached to the `.tab` elements, you could also just use `$(this)`.

  ```
  $('.tab').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  ```

After making these changes, take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/75fcLa6z/).

Comment: and as additional note this would have been easily discovered by checking console for errors

Comment: for one, this was not detected as an error in Google Chrome, secondly my issue persists, the tabs do not switch.http://postimg.org/image/503nidil5/

Comment: @James_Parsons See my edit. `id`s must be unique, they should not be duplicated. Use classes instead. Take a look at this example - http://jsfiddle.net/75fcLa6z/

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thank you, the example was very helpful!